# How to add "selectBoxIt" JQuery plugin in MVC5 project

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a simple project in MVC5 (VS2013) to test the functionality of (selectBoxIt) Jquery plugin to style a ComboBox control for selecting site-language. Everything seems configured correctly, but the "ComboBox" is not affected by the new style of selectBoxIt. In details, this is what I did:

- In *"BundleConfig.cs"* added *"jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"* and *"jquery.selectBoxIt.css"* like this:

  ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
          "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
          "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
          "~/Scripts/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"));

   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
          "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
          "~/Content/site.css",
          "~/Content/jquery.selectBoxIt.css"));
  ```
- In *"Views\Home\Index.cshtml"* under *@section Scripts{}* added:

  ```
  $(function () {
      $('cultureSelect').selectBoxIt();
  });
  ```

  Where `cultureSelect` is the name of the `select` control.
- In *"Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml"* at the very end, added the following `select` tag to display the combo-box control at the top of the screen:

  ```
  using (Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home"))
  {
      <select id="culture" name="culture" class="cultureSelect">
          <option value="en-us" @selected("en-us", culture)>English</option>
          <option value="ar" @selected("ar", culture)>العربية</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="*" onclick="this.form.submit()" />
  }
  ```

  NB: `@selected` is a helper function, just to set *"selected"* word in the right place.

Now, as far as I can see, I tried to follow every single step to configure *"selectBoxIt"*, but with no success! The comboBox control appears but with the standard style. Is there anything I'm missing? Could you please explain what is wrong with my code?